# google map get postal code from latLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

been trying find a way to  extract postcode from latlng position but im not entirely sure how to do it. can someone point me to the right direct please, im using google api autocomplete.

I tried using address_components but it only gives me short/long names and types.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use another service for this. [postcodes.io](http://postcodes.io/) is free, open source and uses open data. The request you are looking for is:

`GET api.postcodes.io/postcodes?lon=:longitude&lat=:latitud`e

Get the long lat from google maps and then make a separate request to a postcode service to get the postcode you are looking for.

The service above covers UK postcodes only. You may need to use multiple services for different countries.

See this [related question on GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121044/latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-into-postal-code-with-town-names)

Comment: true i'll put a disclaimer

Comment: managed to get the postcode and output it but only shows when you drag the marker, I want it to output it as static then update when marker is dragged elsewhere. fiddle is just to show the line of code im using http://jsfiddle.net/pxubhypb/

Comment: Is there a way to find it using geometry.location? similar to what I did to latLng

Answer (score 0):

if the data returned were called "addresses"...

```
var arr = addresses.results[0].address_components,
    i = 0,
    len = arr.length;
for (i; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i].types[0] === "postal_code") {
        alert(arr[i].long_name)
    }
}
```